# legitimate use of `[self loadView]`?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to deal with some code I do not quite understand, similar to this:

In PrimaryViewController:

```
- (void)setup
{
    secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [secondViewController loadViewWithFrame:viewFrame webViewURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
    ...
}
```

And in SecondViewController:

```
- (void)loadViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame webViewURL:(NSString *)url
{
    if (![self isViewLoaded]) {
        [self loadView];
    }
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    ...
}
```

1. Do you think it is legitimate to call `[self loadView]`? (Apple normally don't want you to)
2. What is the point to recreate `self.view` right after?

Note: project minimum SDK is iOS7.

Comment: -loadView is called whenever you access the view property and it hasn't been initialized yet. The if block at the beginning of -loadViewWithFrame is redundant.

Comment: The guy you inherited that code from didn't read Apple's docs and has probably some serious misconceptions about view life cycle.

Comment: This code also makes no sense. The job of `loadView` is to set `self.view`. But after doing that, the next line of code throws away the view that was just loaded.

Comment: I guess I will then remove `[self loadView];`. I wonder if `self.view =` affects the lifecycle of the viewController and calls to `viewWillAppear:` and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `[self loadView]` is not legitimate in the given example.

Recreating `self.view` is not legitimate in the given example: it makes `initWithNibName:bundle:` useless.

So both statements can be removed.